# mod-rewrite question: /test/method is rewritten to test.svg/method

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I noticed an odd (to me) `mod_rewrite` thing happening. Fixing it is not important to me so much as figuring out what's going on. Basically, I have an svg file called `test.svg` in my document root, as well as an `index.php`. My expectation, based on my `.htaccess` file is that visiting `http://localhost/test.svg`  would get me the `.svg` file (and it does), while visiting `http://localhost/test/action` would be rewritten to `index.php/test/action`. Instead, the latter is apparently rewritten to `test.svg/action`, as I receive the message

> The requested URL /test.svg/action was not found on this server.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
# RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I am using a Apache 2.2.12 on Ubuntu (installed via `apt-get`). I think my setup is fairly standard, but I'm not sure exactly what directives or config files would be relevant. I am by no means a sysadmin of any kind, I just use this server to test and develop things locally.

As I said, fixing this issue would be trivial, I just am often confounded by `mod_rewrite` and would like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's HTTP content negotiation feature is automatically translating from "/test" to "/test.svg".  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

You can disable content-negotiation in .htaccess with the directive:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

You can get more information about what mod_rewrite is doing by adding these directives to your Apache configuration (they won't work in .htaccess):

```
RewriteLog /path/to/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

The RewriteLogLevel can be any number from 0 (disabled) to 9 (extremely verbose).  3 should give you enough to see what's going on, but don't use that on a production server.